# What is the process of turning ionic silver solution into colloidal silver solution?

Tags: aqueous-solution

I've looked at a number of different colloidal/ionic "silver solution generators."  After my research I'm under a few impressions and if they're wrong please let me know.

I also am wondering what the product is that one generator sells to add to the ionic silver to create colloidal silver and is it safe to ingest?  I've already seen enough information to believe that ionic silver is safe. I'm wondering if the additive that turns ionic silver into colloidal silver is safe.

Impressions:

When you set up a silver generator, either homemade or store bought, you send a current through two pieces of silver in distilled water.  The particles released into the water are ONLY ionic silver.

Will colloidal silver form over time?  Will ionic silver precipitate or remain suspended?

I could easily build a machine to do this rather than buy one from a dealer that seems to withhold info to either prevent comparisons or to prevent laymen from building their own.  I'm looking for any and all comments related to this topic.  Thanks

To reply to GM's answer: I hesitate to put up pictures or links to the commercial generators since I'm not sure if that would violate the TOU and I have no interest in advertising for anyone.  I imagine if the commercial generators, which work on same principal as the home made ones, didn't generate at least ionic silver they'd have some explaining (lawsuits) to do to someone and they've been on the market for years.

Comment: Polyphenol in green tea may be a better reducing agent. Maybe, possibly, cook ionic silver then put in a cup of green tea. Using distilled water for both. Or is this just too simple

Comment: A common reducing agent would be ascorbic acid(vitamin C). I am not sure though if it can reduce Ag+ to colloidal Ag.

Comment: Ingesting colloidal silver is a bad idea. I'd trust the Mayo Clinic more than I would some quack web site. http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/consumer-health/expert-answers/colloidal-silver/faq-20058061

Comment: @MaxW Thanks for the concern but this isn't a debate about the merits or how to use it. The question is "how does, or can, one colloidal silver to ionic silver.

Answer (score 3):

If you provide a scheme of this mysterious  "colloidal silver generator" would be very interesting, from what I see from googling I see only things like this.

[image]

Up to my knowledge this "colloidal silver generator" has no sense. From instructions notes it seems there are two silver bar in a solution of pure water, as you say, this in fact should create a very slow (because there are no electrolytes) electrolysis of water into $O_2$ and $H_2$ but I don't see any reasons for the producing of colloidal silver.

In chemistry laboratory to produce colloidal silver usually you start from a solution of ionic silver $Ag^{+}$ and reduce it to metallic silver $Ag$.

$$\ce{Ag^{+} + e^{-} -> Ag} $$

## Caution the following is a reaction not a recipe do not ingest the ultimate product of this reaction!!!

Once time I've made a true colloidal silver with Lee-Meisel method (*J.Phys. CHem 1982,86,3391-3395*) if you look at the original paper there are many methods however the following (**method c**) is used most.

> (c) $AgNO_3$ ($90 mg$) was dissolved in $500 mL$ of $H_2O$ and brought to boiling. A solution of $1 %$ sodium citrate ($10 mL$) was added. The solution was kept on boiling for cs. 1h.

The solution should be greenish yellow. If you examine the reaction the $AgNO_3$ is the source of $Ag^{+}$, sodium citrate is the reducing agent that reduce $Ag^{+}$ to $Ag$ and stabilize it. I think colloidal silver generator would be for anyone who makes colloidal solution a dream I assure you is a very complex and tedious process.

Moreover both $Ag^{+}$ and colloidal silver are very difficult to store, the first may  undergo photo-reduction to the metal the second is unstable as many colloidal solution because colloidal solution have grater energy due their larger surface (More energy many times means more instability). Without any stabilizer (such as t-BuONa or citric acid) I don't think the colloid will last long.

However I don't see why you should drink something like this. In fact $Ag^{+}$ has antiseptic properties such as  Mercurochrome,HydrogenPeroxide or Lysol(R) but this don't mean drinking Lysol, Hydrogenperoxide or mercurochorme every morning will make you feel better. I strongly suggest you to do not drink such thing ever.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  People have been ingesting various silver concoctions for hundreds if not thousands of years.  A small handful of people have turned blue b/c they've made improper concoctions or taken way too much. The silver ends up in their skin and when they expose themselves to the sun they basically develop the silver, similar to photography, and turn a bluish color.  This is way beyond very rare though and so far no other negative side effects have been exposed... ionic/colloidal silver is a known topical and internal antiviral, antibacterial, antifungal and is sold as such.

Comment: @hortstu people have ingested various toxic concoctions for thousands, this doesn't mean you have to continue to ingest them. There are many more effective and **selective** antibiotics. $Ag^{+}$ kills every biotic form and may cause to you argyria.

Comment: other than argyria, which is extremely rare amongst people using silver, what other toxic effects are proven? None that I can find. There are extensive studies showing the benefits of silver.  "Effective and selective" antibiotics is a big part of the reason we have antibiotic resistant bacteria are becoming a bigger and bigger problem.  Finally antibiotics don't work on viral or fungal infections.

Comment: also this isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: @hortstu I'm quoting from your question "and is it safe to ingest?" for me the answer is "no":  ["In 1999, the FDA prohibited the sale of over-the-counter drugs containing colloidal silver or silver salts because they had not been shown to be safe and effective."](http://nccam.nih.gov/health/silver). $Ag$ builds up in the tissues of the body moreover up to my knowledge there is no evidence that $Ag^{+}$ can have effects on viral infections. However you are free to do what you want I only tell you what a know!

Comment: If I worded my question poorly I apologize. I meant is the additive that turns ionic silver into colloidal silver safe for ingestion. I already believe silver in moderation to be safe... and we can debate the efficacy and intent of the FDA somewhere else.

Comment: @G M   "In 1999, the FDA prohibited the sale of over-the-counter drugs containing colloidal silver or silver salts because they had not been shown to be safe and effective."  The FDA never proved Vioxx to be safe or effective either but they allowed that on the market... Also they may not allow it in drugs but as a dietary supplement it is commercially available.   http://store.peacefulmountain.com/products/ionic-colloidal-silver

Comment: @hortstu ok, however keep to investigate!  I hope someone else could give you a better answer. Maybe you should change the title including _"How "colloidal silver generators" works?"_ I hope your question will have more attention from community!

Comment: @ GM thank you. I appreciate your help. I think I understand how the generator works to create ionic silver. I'm trying to find the steps from there to colloidal.

Comment: @hortstu There are better ways to get rid of money. I suggest pouring lighter fluid on it and throwing a lit match on top.  More seriously though there is no proven benefit from silver ingestion.  Argyria will make you purple for the rest of your life. If you are dead set on ingesting silver, just buy an ounce of silver nitrate and make a dilute stock solution but keep it out of light.  An ounce will cost about $30 at most and last for life a silver generator will rip you off for $300 to give you what you could have bought for $30.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to G M's answer, there are more ways to produce colloidal, or more properly nanoparticles from silver nitrate.

The fastest one is using sodium tetrahydroborate (or borohydride). It takes a couple of seconds and if you don't deliberately put something to the solution nanoparticles will be stable for months (most probably longer). A polymer can be used to prevent coagulation of colloids yet as explained we did not need.

Citrate is also an option or any other similar organic acid but they are not as an effective reducing agent as borohydride so you need to heat the solution almost to boiling to get some activity. On the contrary, we always used ices to at least reduce the activity of borohydride to control the reaction.

Other than these, I have also synthesized silver nanoparticles by brewed, boiled or simply left tea, and also Artemisia absinthium (there are actually tens of articles on making silver nanoparticles using inorganic or organic chemicals, or even direct extracts of tea orange etc.

I emphasized nanoparticle more than colloid here since you will only have colorful silver solutions when particles are in between 10-100 nm in diameters. Yellow for smallest and black for largest, red and purple/violet between.

In short, these are the proper methods to produce silver nanoparticles in chemical or green synthesis.